# Unable to change default /etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties location for different kafka connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using multiple kafka connectors. But every connector is writing log within same connect.log file. But I want connectors to write different log files. For that, during startup I need to change default /etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties file. But unable to change it.

Sample Start Script:

```
/usr/bin/connect-standalone  ../properties/sample-worker.properties  ../properties/sample-connector.properties > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Is there any way to change default /etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties file during the startup of connectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka uses log4j, and has a variable for overriding it

```
export KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///some/other/log4j.properties"
connect-standalone.sh ...
```

Generally, it would be best to use `connect-distributed` and use some log aggregation tool like the ELK stack to parse through log events for different connectors

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. I will check this on next Monday.  Yes, previously you  advised me to use connect-distributed in production. And I have convinced my seniors to use kafka-connect in distributed mode in production. Our product is not in production yet. We are going to use kafka-connect in distributed mode in production. Thanks a lot.