# Task becomes UNASSIGNED for Debezium MySQL source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, debezium-engine, debezium-server

I am using debezium 1.9. I created a connector using below config

```
{ 
    "name": "user_management_db-connector-5", 
    "config": { 
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", 
        "tasks.max": "1", 
        "database.hostname": "XXXX", 
        "database.port": "3306", 
        "database.user": "XXX", 
        "database.password": "XXX", 
        "database.server.id": "12345", 
        "database.server.name": "ula-stg-db", 
        "database.include.list": "user_management_db", 
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka.ulastg.xyz:9094,kafka.ulastg.xyz:9092", 
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.user_management_db",
        "snapshot.mode" : "schema_only", 
        "snapshot.locking.mode" : "none",
        "table.include.list": "user_management_db.user,user_management_db.store,user_management_db.store_type,user_management_db.user_segment,user_management_db.user_segment_mapping",
        "transforms":"Reroute", 
        "transforms.Reroute.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter", 
        "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex":"(.*)user_management_db(.+)", 
        "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement":"$1cdc", 
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false", 
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "topic.creation.default.include": "ula-stg-db.+",  
        "topic.creation.default.partitions": 20,
        "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 2, 
        "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy": "delete",
        "topic.creation.default.delete.retention.ms": 300000,
        "errors.log.enable": true,
        "errors.log.include.messages" :true
    } 
}
```

The connector gets created and I can see events in the topic ***ula-stge-db.cdc***

The problem is after some time ( approximately a day ) I see events stop getting populated. I do not see any error in connector logs.

It only throws a generic info in regular interval

```
2022-07-12 09:24:25,654 INFO || WorkerSourceTask{id=promo_management_db-connector-5-0} Either no records were produced by the task since the last offset commit, or every record has been filtered out by a transformation or dropped due to transformation or conversion errors. [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask]
```

The connector status is now shown as below

```
{
  "name": "user_management_db-connector-5",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "172.31.65.156:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "UNASSIGNED",
      "worker_id": "172.31.71.28:8083"
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

How to debug further ?

P.S: I am connecting to AWS RDS MySql. And Kafka is hosted in an EC2.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances running (2 pods of debezium on k8s for example) , can you change the log level to say INFO or DEBUG (log4j logger config for Kafka connect) and see if you get any logs ?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple instance running. Where do I set the log level ? I am using the debezium community docker image directly.

Comment: you'd probably have to look at KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69127673/unable-to-change-default-etc-kafka-connect-log4j-properties-location-for-differ.

Comment: Will running multiple instance cause this problem ?

Comment: Should not , you should have one active worker at anypoint and fallback if it fails. Have you checked the status on both the containers ?

Comment: I am using the Loadbalancer status endpoint. But, new events are not getting produced so I assume, Task is not running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246396/discussion-between-partha-and-ramachandran-a-g).

Comment: Hi @Partha were you able to resolve this issue. We are also facing the same issue with our source connector.